# How can set Datepicker to take the complett height of the View?

Tags: javafx, datepicker, calendar, gluon-mobile

I have a Datepicker in Javafx 8.[image]
    I have used this Code but it not take the komplett Size for the Views

```
final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
    DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(datePicker);
    javafx.scene.Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();

    datePicker.setMaxHeight(6000.);
    datePicker.setMinHeight(6000.);
    datePicker.setPrefHeight(6000.);
    datePicker.setOnAction((event) -> {
        LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue();
        System.err.println("Selected date: " + date);
    });


    primary1.setTop(popupContent);
```

I want to make it (Datepicker) fullscreen.

[image]

Comment: Gluon Charm already provides a custom DatePicker control

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes it works fine. I update the Post.

Comment: @JoséPereda Do you know how i can change the Cancel and Accept button of the Dialog to French?

Comment: Not easily. The control doesn't allow i18n yet, but you can get the buttons with `DatePicker.getButtons()`, and then change their text.

Comment: @JoséPereda It works fine

Comment: @JoséPereda I have Posted i new Post. Can you help me please?

Comment: @JoséPereda I have Posted i new Post. Can you help me please?